# How to solve Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, jwt, axios

> [This question is original in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284344/c%C3%B3mo-resolver-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy), I used Google Translate
>   for post the same question here, I really so sorry if the syntax isn't
>   the best, I did my better work to translate the fully question here.
>    **THANKS!**

---

Good morning everyone

I have a Rest API in C #, and I have several GET and POST methods in that API, I tried all the methods using Postman and they worked perfectly, they all give me the answers I expect, the problem arises when I'm trying to consume them from my Front, I tried using Axios and Ajax and everyone throws the following exception:

• Axios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• jQuery Ajax:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I managed to get this error more accurate haha:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I thought it could be first because the API was in https and my front in http, so I placed both in https and both in http and this did not solve it.

The way I am consuming it is as follows:

• Axios:

```
let url = this.apiSeguridad + "usuario/";              
let data = {
            Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
            UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
            Password: btoa(this.password),
            Public_IP: this.publicIP,
            Private_IP: this.localIP
           };
console.log(url, data);
let resultApi = await axios.post(url, data);
```

I also tried using the following code:

```
let url = this.apiSeguridad + "usuario/";
let config = {
            headers: {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "cache-control": "no-cache"
                 }
             };
let data = JSON.stringify({
           Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
           UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
           Password: btoa(this.password),
           Public_IP: this.publicIP,
           Private_IP: this.localIP
           });
console.log(url, data);
let resultApi = await axios.post(url, data,config);
```

And it didn't work out.

In Ajax I tried in similar ways but it was more to validate if the request was valid but throws the same error, I am interested in making it work in axios.

GET requests work perfectly, I only get the error in POST requests.

The configuration I have of the API on the web.config is this:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And the POST method that I want to consume is like this:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Well, now, where I think the problem may be is that I am using `JWT` in my API and added this line of code in the`WebApiConfig.cs`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

That I am supposed to validate the header for all requests to methods in which I have the attribute `[Authorize]`

To implement the JWT I used [this website](https://enmilocalfunciona.io/construyendo-una-web-api-rest-segura-con-json-web-token-en-net-parte-ii/), that's where I took and added that line of code.

I would like your help to be able to solve it, I don't know if it's API configuration or how I consume the API from axios or what.

The application from postman works correctly and answers me as I would like, here is an example:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I do not add anything else to that request.

Thanks to Miguel Zarate's request (In the original Spanish post) to use Fiddler4 to verify the requests, this is what the tool shows me:

• From Postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• From the Front:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

This seems to be the most obvious difference between the results:

• Postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

• Front:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The funny thing is that when I delete from the web.config the header `<add name =" Access-Control-Allow-Origin "value =" * "/>` the Postman continues to make the request without problems, but from my Front I do not I can make no GET request until I place it again, but the failure continues with the POST requests.

> CURL from Google Chrome console:

• CMD:

```
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "^{^\^"Nit_ID^\^":^\^"899999284^\^",^\^"UserName^\^":^\^"sasfdm^\^",^\^"Password^\^":^\^"NDU0NjU0NjU0^\^",^\^"Public_IP^\^":^\^"181.49.144.244^\^",^\^"Private_IP^\^":^\^"192.168.253.102^\^"^}" --compressed
```

• Bash:

```
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"Nit_ID":"899999284","UserName":"sasfdm","Password":"NDU0NjU0NjU0","Public_IP":"181.49.144.244","Private_IP":"192.168.253.102"}' --compressed
```

• CMD: All:

```
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/1032494911" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "DNT: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" --compressed &
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/tipodocumento/899999284/1032494911" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "DNT: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" --compressed &
curl "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: http://localhost:8080/" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "^{^\^"Nit_ID^\^":^\^"899999284^\^",^\^"UserName^\^":^\^"sasfdm^\^",^\^"Password^\^":^\^"MTIzNDU2Nzg5^\^",^\^"Public_IP^\^":^\^"181.49.144.244^\^",^\^"Private_IP^\^":^\^"192.168.253.102^\^"^}" --compressed
```

• Bash All:

```
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/1032494911' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' --compressed ;
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/tipodocumento/899999284/1032494911' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' --compressed ;
curl 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"Nit_ID":"899999284","UserName":"sasfdm","Password":"MTIzNDU2Nzg5","Public_IP":"181.49.144.244","Private_IP":"192.168.253.102"}' --compressed
```

---

> The error lies in how to correctly send the DATA to the POST method, since if a POST method is created that does not allow data there is no problem, what it consumes without problems, when it receives parameters it does not, then **how do I send those correctly? data with Axios?**

When I don't put parameters in the API like `[FromBody] InfoEntryValidateUserClass data` the command`let resultApi = await axios.post (url);`works.

If I add the `[FromBody] InfoEntryValidateUserClass data` as a parameter in the API and send the data using`JSON.stringify ({...})`I receive`null` in the data sent, but if I do not use it, it appears again the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https: // localhost: 44377 / api / user /' from origin 'http: // localhost: 8080' has been blocked by CORS policy`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The error is in how to send that data that the API is waiting for, the class I refer to is this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass
    {
        public string Nit_ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Public_IP { get; set; }
        public string Private_IP { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am sending the data like this:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Password: btoa(this.password),
    Public_IP: this.publicIP,
    Private_IP: this.localIP
});
```

Comment: You have to compare the first request of the working code with the non working code.  And then check the status of the response to see if you are getting 200 OK.  I think your code is working.  You are getting a response.  The response is GZIP so make sure in your code you unzip the data before using.  I suspect the working code it automatically gets unzipped.  In c# you must add code to unzip.  It also looks like the code that fails is setting the language.  Some webpages will not support more than one language.

Comment: When you say "you must add code to unzip" what code I must add?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Compression_GZipStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: The error isn't  from CORS, I do other Post method without params and it works, the problem is how I send the params data from the API

Comment: Make the Request Headers look exactly like the working.  Check to see if the response is giving 200 OK.  If you are getting 200 OK then you are getting a good response and the issue is with your code that is doing the processing of the response.

Comment: When the API recibe params like `[FromBody]InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass data` it doesn't work, if I remove the params, the command `let resultApi = await axios.post(url,data);` works.

Comment: I add `[FromBody]InfoEntryValidateUsuarioClass data` in Params, but I receive `null` in the data when I use `JSON.stringify({...})` to send data, If I don't use `JSON.stringify` y get the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy`

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` is incorrect; axios automatically sets `content-type: application/json` and serializes objects when you post objects as data. It may be converting your string into a JSON string, which is not what you want. Another issue I see here is that you're trying to make an http request from an https host page, which is going to get blocked. I'd recommend you post the full _code_ for your server configuration; never use screenshots of code. It's hard to tell what your CORS configuration is.

Comment: Look at the sniffer and see the differences.

Comment: The problem is when I add any Headers, for example `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` I get the CORS error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verifying several things, and with the help of many people in the chat that opened, we found that the solution is in a web.config and CORS configuration directly in the API.

The following are added to the web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
     <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>        
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file the package was added

```cs
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

To add the safety of CORS, what was placed there was:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configuración y servicios de API web

            //Configuración para verificar la seguridad del CORS
            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

            // Rutas de API web
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And the whole issue of applications with Axios, both GET and POST, has already worked.

When I just needed to send data in the POST I did it as follows:

```js
let data = {
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Password: btoa(this.password),
    Public_IP: this.publicIP,
    Private_IP: this.localIP
};
//Verificamos los datos del usuario
let resultApi = await axios.post(
     "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario",
     data
);
let result = resultApi.data;
```

To send data in the header with axes, I did it as follows:

```js
let data = {
    Nit_ID: this.userInfo.nit_ID.ID,
    UserName: this.userInfo.userName.ID,
    Code: this.verificationCode
};
console.log(localStorage.getItem("DoubleFactorToken"));
let headers = {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("DoubleFactorToken")
};
let resultApi = await axios.post(
     "https://localhost:44377/api/usuario/verifydoublefactorcode",
     data,
     { headers: headers }
);

console.log(resultApi.data);
```

Thank you very much to all who took their time to collaborate.